# Can you assign a css entry an html selector and a class selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If I have the following piece of CSS:

```
p {
color:red;
}
```

This will apply to all P html elements. Is there a way I can also assign a class based selector to that same css object? So I could then also have `<h1 class="redText">` which would also use the css object above - as well as it applying to all `<p>` elements?

Comment: You can have a comma-separated list of multiple selectors.  What seems to be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.redText,p` to select everything with a class of "redText", and every "P" element. The `.` is the class selector, so `.redText` matches every thing with that class. Use a comma to separate multiple element matches.

```css
.redText,
p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="redText">Red Text!!!!!</h1>

<p>Red text!</p>

<h1>Normal text!!!</h1>
```